# Converting Filemaker to SQL or another database system

Tags: database, sql, import, convert, filemaker

Currently at work we have a Filemaker database running on Filemaker Server 7 on a Windows Small Business Server 2003. I would like to change from using Filemaker to a different database, one with a web based front-end. It doesn't have to be MySQL, though that is were my minimal database training is. It could be anything so long as we don't need a client to connect to it and can just use a web browser.

I am looking for a tool that can convert the database and hopefully the forms as well. Are there any good ones out there? Can I merely import the data into another program and then create a new series of forms?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may want to look at [FmPro Migrator](http://www.fmpromigrator.com/products/fmpro_migrator/index.html). It will convert FileMaker Pro (2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10) to a SQL Database (MySQL, Oracle, Access, Microsoft SQL Server, Sybase, DB2, OpenBase, PostgreSQL, FrontBase, SQLite and Valentina).

You could also [FileMaker Instant Web Publishing](http://www.filemaker.com/support/technologies/iwp.html). It's part of FileMaker Server Advanced and is also part of the client FileMaker. It's quite easy to use as it allows you to design your layouts in FileMaker and lets your users access the database via a web browser.

You can also access the data via ODBC from your other database or program.

Lastly, you can export FileMaker's data from within the FileMaker client program to an XML or text format and the import into your new database format and build new forms and layouts.

Comment: thanks for your help. Have you had any experience with FmPro Migrator. How well does it convert the layouts?

Comment: I tried and old version and the conversion was a bit rough. It should be better now but I can't speak for it.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, newer versions of FmPro Migrator also convert the layouts into PHP web applications, as well as other development environments. There is more info available on this web page:

http://www.fmpromigrator.com/services/php_conversion.html